# Trying to manipulate images using Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to learn Python, this is the first code that I have written:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # Filename: read_image.py


    f=open('1.raw','r+b')
    image=f.read()
    f.close()


    f=open('copy.raw','w+b')
    f.write(image)
    f.close()

    for i in range(1,256):
        image[i]=0
```

In the first part I am simply reading a '.raw' image as a binary file and making a copy of it. This part works fine on its own and I get a copy of the image after execution of the code. However I wish to manipulate this image, for starters I was trying to blacken the first line of the image, however I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/read_image.py", line 15, in <module>
    image[i]=0
TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
```

I tried using 'int' type variables by copying the image into them, however the error persists except instead of 'bytes' object does not support assignment, I get 'int' object does not support assignment. How should I go about solving this problem?

Please note this is a grayscale image, and the pixel values range from 0 to 255, I tried printing the array image on the shell and it showed me values in this range.

Answer (score 3):

In Python `bytes` are immutable. You can't change them, that's why it gives you an error when you try to do item assignment. You could convert your immutable `bytes` object into a [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
image = bytearray(image)
for i in range(1,256):
    image[i]=0
```

Comment: Okay, tried converting it to a bytesarray, get the following error:  NameError: name 'bytesarray' is not defined,

Comment: Sorry, it's `bytearray`. I did typo that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The 'int' object doesnt support assignment too.. should I convert it to an intarray as well.. Coz I may have to manipulate integer arrays as well in the future..

Comment: @Kedar No, you just use a normal list and fill it with ints: ``a = [1,2,3]; a[1]=5``

Comment: Hello Thomas... But how can I create lists without initializing them? Because I want to store all the pixel values in an integer/float array and then manipulate this array and then round off this array and copy the values back into a byte array... Can this be achieved in Python?

Answer (score 3):

If you're really trying to do image processing in Python, try the Python Imaging Library* (PIL) found here: http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/

[*] Keep in mind that you will have to use Python 2.x as opposed to 3.x if you use this library, unfortunately as is currently the case with a lot of powerful python libraries.

Comment: I just wanted to write my first bit of code... But Ill be sure to use the library if I have to implement anything.. read the documentation.. seems very useful.. Thank you!